# How to fetch CoreData entities with specific ID with NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I have `NewsEntity` CoreData NSManagedObject with two attributes: `id` and `name`. Also I have an array of IDs.

`let IDs = ["9998", "10012", "12023"]`

How to fetch all `NewsEntity` excluding entities with id from the array `IDs`.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NewsEntity> = NewsEntity.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (id IN %@)", argumentArray: IDs)

let result = try CoreDataStack.shared.viewContent.fetch(request)
```

When I try to run this code my app crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: `argumentArray` is the wrong API. It expects as many placeholders as number of items in the array.

Comment: Thanks, @vadian. It works!